# Php sorting based on ID and ParentID

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**i have the following array structure:**

```
   |  ID  |  CategoryName  | ParentID 
    _________________________________
       1  |  Movies        | -1
    _________________________________
       2  |  Series        | -1
    _________________________________
       3  |  ActionMovies  |  1
    _________________________________
       4  |  HorrorMovies  |  1
    _________________________________
       5  |  ComedySeries  |  2
    _________________________________
       6  |  TVShows       | -1
```

My goal is to reach the following structure

**Goal:**

```
   |  ID  |  CategoryName  | ParentID 
    _________________________________
       1  |  Movies        | -1
    _________________________________
       3  |  ActionMovies  |  1
    _________________________________
       4  |  HorrorMovies  |  1
    _________________________________
       2  |  Series        | -1
    _________________________________
       5  |  ComedySeries  |  2
    _________________________________
       6  |  TVShows       | -1
```

Or explained in word:

- Parent-Categories have `ParentID = -1` (Example Movies)
- All categories keep their original ID-Number
- Should come listed directly after their ParentCategory (Example ActionMovies)
- RootCategories without Children, come listed at the end of array. (Example TVShows)

How can i achieve this best with PHP? I have no access to the original Mysql query, so that is not an option :)

i have started with this code, but i am not sure it is the right path, and with minimal efforts/readability

```
        $tmpList = Categories_Models_Main::getAllCategories();



    $categoryData = array();
    foreach ($tmpList as $index => $categoryObject) {
        $categoryData[] = array('id' => $categoryObject->id,
                                 'CategoryName' => $categoryObject->parentId,
                                 'name' => $categoryObject->name);


    }

    ///let us assume $categoryData is original state.

    ///Beginning of manipulation and re-sorting of $tmpList


    foreach ($categoryData as $key => $value) {

        $mainId[$key] = $value['id'];

        $parentId[$key] = $value['parentId'];

    }

    array_multisort($parentId, $mainId, $categoryData);
```

Comment: What kind of array you have to be sorted? If you don’t feel like fighting with php’s sorting functions, manually going through the array and collecting the fields used to sort and then going through the whole thing using the sorted field to collect all values in correct order oughta be feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the main array into two, one with those nodes that doesn't have childs and other with rests of items.

Do the sorting into array of items with array_multisort function and do too a sorting into array of categories without childs using the criteria that you want. The final step will be push the array without childs to the other.

This form isn't the most efficient, but to have a first approach is valid, after this, you can dispense time optimizing the code.

Comment: hmmm...if i have no other choices, i will try this splitting idea...seems as my best option sofar :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = array(
    array("foo", "bar", "5"),
    array("barr", "baz", "9"),
    array("nyan", "nyu", "2")
);

usort($input, function($a, $b) {
    if($a[2] < $b[2]) {
        return -1;
    } else if($a[2] > $b[2]) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

var_dump($input);
```

Do you mean something like this? The idea is to manually compare the contents of the array using condition you know. Since the thing what is to be sorted is unique, the logic *how to sort* must be always implemented. With PHP, PHP’s sorting functions most of time does it correctly.

Comment: does not look too bad, but i do not think it is what i need....since i have arrays in arrays....and those subarrays can be many.

Comment: Do you know what you are sorting?

Comment: i am sorting based on ParentID.

Comment: Isn’t the input you have pretty much what I wrote? Please do var_dump() for a data and attach it too to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that this does not answer your question, but might give you some ideas how to make your life easier. This is javascript approach of the problem, but this way you won't even have to think about sorting anything. You just provide parents and children and it is sorted for you and ready to use. A pretty nice way in my opinion. Yet it is probably irrelevant to what you are trying to do, but maybe for some other similar problem you would see this as a solution: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart

Comment: looks neat Andrius, but i really need to solve it on array level :)

Comment: Have you given a try of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580248/sorting-an-array-into-a-multidimensional-array-based-on-parent-id

Comment: Also interesting with tree structure :D but not exactly what i need....i will work on it, and let u know guys if i reach a result.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this problem is by using a bottom up approach (i am referring to the pyramids).

**Explanation**

We need to start with rows (entries) within an array that do not have parents. In my case, it's any element that has "parent_id = 0". Once we have those, we need to build children elements for each parent element.

The latter part would be done recursively by calling sorting method until the element which we are processing has not children. The results from the sorting method are passed down to the previous array point until the array is complete.

**Code**

```
Class Categories {
    private $cats;

    public function getAllCategoriesSorted() {
        /**
         * $this->cats = [
         *      'id' => x, 'parent_id' => x
         * ];
         */
        $this->cats = Category::get()->toArray();

        # find categories with no parents
        $keys = array_keys(array_column($this->cats, 'parent_id'), 0);

        $return = [];
        # loop through each and populate each one
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $return[$this->cats[$key]['id']] = $this->sortCategories($this->cats[$key]);
        }

        dd($return);
    }

    private function sortCategories($currentElement) {
        # we need to check if current element has any children
        $keys = array_keys(array_column($this->cats, 'parent_id'), $currentElement['id']);

        if ($keys === false || empty($keys)) {
            # we are dealing with childless element, we should return it as it is
            return $currentElement;
        }

        # we are dealing with element that has children, we need to loop through each child
        $currentElement['children'] = [];

        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $currentElement['children'][$this->cats[$key]['id']] = $this->sortCategories($this->cats[$key]);
        }

        return $currentElement;
    }
}
```

**Example result**

```
array:2 [▼
  65 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 65
    "name" => "Parent 1"
    "parent_id" => 0
    "children" => array:14 [▼
      66 => array:4 [▼
        "id" => 66
        "name" => "Child 1"
        "parent_id" => 65
        "children" => array:22 [▶]
      ]
      87 => array:4 [▼
        "id" => 87
        "name" => "Child 2"
        "parent_id" => 65
        "children" => array:31 [▶]
      ]
      117 => array:4 [▶]
      118 => array:4 [▶]
      120 => array:4 [▶]
      124 => array:4 [▶]
      125 => array:4 [▶]
      127 => array:4 [▶]
      225 => array:4 [▶]
      305 => array:4 [▶]
      434 => array:4 [▶]
      321 => array:4 [▶]
      348 => array:4 [▶]
      468 => array:4 [▶]
    ]
  ]
  64 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 64
    "name" => "Parent 2"
    "parent_id" => 0
    "children" => array:5 [▼
      128 => array:4 [▶]
      132 => array:4 [▼
        "id" => 132
        "name" => "Child 3"
        "parent_id" => 64
        "children" => array:22 [▼
          202 => array:3 [▶]
          203 => array:3 [▼
            "id" => 203
            "name" => "Child 4"
            "parent_id" => 132
          ]
          204 => array:3 [▶]
          205 => array:3 [▶]
          206 => array:3 [▶]
          207 => array:3 [▶]
          208 => array:3 [▶]
          209 => array:3 [▶]
          210 => array:3 [▶]
          211 => array:3 [▶]
          212 => array:3 [▶]
          213 => array:3 [▶]
          214 => array:3 [▶]
          215 => array:3 [▶]
          216 => array:3 [▶]
          217 => array:3 [▶]
          218 => array:3 [▶]
          220 => array:3 [▶]
          221 => array:3 [▶]
          222 => array:3 [▶]
          223 => array:3 [▶]
          224 => array:3 [▶]
        ]
      ]
      134 => array:4 [▶]
      394 => array:4 [▶]
      454 => array:4 [▶]
    ]
  ]
]
```