# Nesting Array Items Based on a Value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I have an array like this:

```
0 => ['id'=> 1, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => null],
1 => ['id'=> 2, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => 1],
2 => ['id'=> 3, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => 2],
3 => ['id'=> 4, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => 2],
4 => ['id'=> 5, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => 4]
```

How can I iterate over this to create a nested array where items are inside of each other based on their parent_id?

---

Result to look like something like this:

```
0 => ['id'=> 1, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => null, 'children' => [['id'=> 2, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => 1, 'children' => [['id'=> 3, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => 2], ['id'=> 4, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => 2, 'children' => [['id'=> 4, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => 4]]]]]]]
```

Comment: Show array result you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580248/sorting-an-array-into-a-multidimensional-array-based-on-parent-id or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661298/sorting-array-for-every-child-coming-after-parent

Comment: None of those solutions worked.

Comment: Your array contains 2 entries for index 3! So only the last one will be persisted. I think this is an error in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **recursive** function :

```
$arr = array(
0 => ['id'=> 1, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => null],
1 => ['id'=> 2, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => 1],
2 => ['id'=> 3, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => 1],
3 => ['id'=> 4, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => 2],
);

function add_childs(array $elements, $parentId = null) {
    $parent = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
          echo "in if".$element['id']."<br>";
            $children = add_childs($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $parent[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $parent;
}

$result = add_childs($arr);
print_r($result);
```

example : https://eval.in/745350

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I understood the question other way (parent attached to child)...

You have to iterate over users to look for every parent/child pairing.

```
<?php
$users = [
0 => ['id'=> 1, 'name' => 'A', 'parent_id' => null],
1 => ['id'=> 2, 'name' => 'B', 'parent_id' => 1],
2 => ['id'=> 3, 'name' => 'C', 'parent_id' => 2],
3 => ['id'=> 4, 'name' => 'D', 'parent_id' => 2],
3 => ['id'=> 4, 'name' => 'E', 'parent_id' => 4]
];

foreach($users as $user){
    foreach($users as &$parent){
        if($user['parent_id'] == $parent['id']){
            $parent['children'][] = $user;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($users);

?>
```